# typesafe joins in spark for 3.x

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dependencies, apache-calcite

In old versions of Spark 3.x

```
import org.apache.calcite.sql.JoinType
```

Calcite was exposed.
That meant a JOIN could not only be executed in a strongly typed fashion for dataframes (notice I do not mean datasets) by feeding: `JoinType.LEFT.name`.

Calcite is no longer exposed for 3.x.

Therefore, currently one would need to fall back to stringly typed join types (which is a bad thing I think).
Is there a similar possibility for another class I am overlooking (which actually is exposed)?
I am a bit reluctant to manually add calcite in my user code as this might result in conflicting classes (but it would be a viable option).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.JoinType
```

seems to do the trick